# How to integrate Xcode instruments with CI pipeline?

Tags: ios, swift, performance, continuous-integration, pipeline

How to integrate Xcode instruments app with CI pipelines and generate reports for leaks, allocations, memory usage etc...? or Is it possible to generate performance report in CI pipelines?

Comment: This question would be better formatted as two. Maybe ask about Xcode - CI integrations first ?

Comment: I want to generate performance report in CI pipelines? As per my knowledge we can generate leaks, allocations with instruments only. Is it possible to generate leaks, allocations in CI pipelines? @NickT